# jQuery - using live instead of bind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I'm using plupload and I want to dynamically update my gallery (jquery.ajax()) where I use lightbox & etc (in other words I want to keep the js working in ajax loaded content) when all the files are uploaded.

What I'm doing now is this

```
var upload = $el.pluploadQueue();
upload.bind('UploadComplete',function(){
//ajax & etc
}
```

of course`.bind()` is not for future elements and I tried to change it to `.live()` (`upload.live('UploadComplete',function(){`) but for some reason the event is not performed.

I also tried with `.on()`:

`$(document).on('UploadComplete', upload, function() {`

and `delegate`:

`$(document).delegate(upload, 'UploadComplete', function() {`

but the same thing as `live()`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `live`, its deprecated (and dead since 1.9). Use `on` or maybe `delegate` instead. From http://api.jquery.com/live/:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: I tried with them too, but no luck. Can you give me an example how this `upload.bind('UploadComplete',function(){` should look like with `delegate`?

Comment: Okay you mentioned now that you are using plupload. There might be something else going on here. I'm suspecting its not a problem in the binding, but instead somewhere else in the code. I'd start by double-checking that the plupload plugin is initialized and used properly.

Comment: **`live` is dead since 1.9**, not deprecated but removed!

Comment: I mentioned plupload from the beginning. I double and triple checked everything and I can't understand why it works with `.bind()` only. Can I do what I need using bind()? Every idea will be appriciated. THANKS!

Comment: @gdoron I tried using on like this - `$(document).on('UploadComplete', upload, function() {` but again the event is not performed. That's why I asked for example using `delegate` or `on`.

Comment: @user2081339, `$(document).on('UploadComplete', '{selector}', function() {`

Comment: which is my selector? isn't it the `upload`?

Comment: See the other answer. It really looks like the `bind` here is not even from jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Although at first glance the `bind` method appears to be the jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), a quick search through the Plupload API shows it implements its own [bind](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/#class_plupload.Uploader.html-bind) method that just happens to have the same signature as the JQuery version. So your original code is just fine and doesn't use any deprecated functionality.

Edit:

It seems there's two questions: is `bind` being deprecated (answered in the previous paragraph) and how can I display the uploaded image once the upload is complete. As to the second question, hopefully this example will get you started:

```
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {
  $.each(files, function(index, file) {
    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'http://your-url.com/your-upload-directory/' + file.name);
    img.load(function() {
      //add lightbox specific code here
      $('.img-container').append(img);
    });
  });
});
```

If you need more specific help with displaying the images, you'll have to update your question with more detailed code examples.

Comment: Okay :) Thank you very much for letting us know, but how I can solve my problem?

Comment: @user2081339 - Not sure I understand your question. Sounds like your original code works, but you were worried about relying on a soon to be removed feature. While the jQuery `bind` is removed in later versions, the Plupload `bind` (a completely unrelated method) has no mention of deprecation in the [API](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/#class_plupload.Uploader.html-bind).

Comment: my problem: I can't use anything with javascript in the content loaded with ajax - lightbox & etc

Comment: @user2081339 - Updated my answer to include how to display the image after upload is complete.

Comment: thank you for taking your time, but I want to update my whole gallery because I'm separating the files by their size, extension & etc. Ideas?

Comment: Each `file` object has `size` and `name` properties. I suggest reading the API and editing your question to be much more detailed if you need any more help.